# Buddhism Stack Exchange website

Tags: discussion, site-proposal

Currently there are Stack Exchange websites for all three Abrahamic religions:

- [Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/)
- [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/)
- [Judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/)

I listed them in no particular order. Are there any plans to create one for Buddhism as well?

Comment: Check Area51. If there's no such proposal yet, you could make your own.

Comment: You've listed them by date descending. But it's instane that you were downvoted by overzelous strict-mode speakers because of that ^^

Comment: @ŁukaszLech - I believe the downvotes are due to the lack of research. There is a place for Stack Exchange site proposals, and SO Meta is not it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Plans?

If the community suggests a site and it gets enough support, it will be created.

This happens in [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

And in fact, there is a [Buddhism](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45110/buddhism) proposal. You can go and commit to it, if you so choose.

Comment: cool thanks, i didn't know that. I'll support the proposal :)